# Smarty exception Message: property 'data' does not exist

Tags: php, smarty, slim

I keep getting this error:

> Type: SmartyException Message: property 'data' does not exist. 
>   File:
>   D:\Work\Apache\htdocs\anvelopebv.ro\Smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   Line: 810

and i dont know what's the problem :(

```
require 'Smarty/Smarty.class.php';
$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->setTemplateDir('../Templates/');
$smarty->setCompileDir('../Templates/Compiled');
$smarty->setCacheDir('../Templates/Cache');
$smarty->setCacheDir('../Templates/Configs');

$smarty->debugging = true;

require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => $smarty  
));

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('home.tpl', array('test' => 'works'));
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on, from the code you shared?

Comment: i don't get any error in my code.... only in smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 810

Comment: Then make sure that file exists in the server, and if it does, make sure it has read permission, so that php can access it.

Comment: it does have acces and it exists, if the file wasn't there i would get a fatal error but i just get a smarty exception ...

Comment: What is `render` function looks like?

Comment: Can you share the `home.tpl` code?  At first glance it seems like the view is expecting a `data` variable, but you're only passing in `test`. That might not be the case, but without seeing `home.tpl` it's tough to know.